# How continue train inception model from checkpoint in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, restore, checkpoint

I have loaded pretrained inception model:

`if FLAGS.pretrained_model_checkpoint_path:
      assert tf.gfile.Exists(FLAGS.pretrained_model_checkpoint_path)
      variables_to_restore = tf.get_collection(
          slim.variables.VARIABLES_TO_RESTORE)
      restorer = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
      restorer.restore(sess, FLAGS.pretrained_model_checkpoint_path)
      print('%s: Pre-trained model restored from %s' %
            (datetime.now(), FLAGS.pretrained_model_checkpoint_path))`

And trained model on my data, by using [flowers_train.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/flowers_train.py)

After train completed, the loss was about 1.0 and the model was saved in specified directory.

Now I want to continue training, 
So, I restor model:

`if FLAGS.checkpoint_dir is not None:
        # restoring from the checkpoint file
        ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)
        tf.train.Saver().restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)`

And continue train model, but loss on first step is about 6.5, which in fact means, that model wasn't initialised at all.

Here is the whole content of [inception_train.py](https://gist.github.com/erebus1/48a24a894cb7526c4f26658cd19a7599), which were modified from this [inception_train.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_train.py)

First train I was start by:

`bazel-bin/inception/flowers_train   --train_dir="{$TRAIN_DIR}"   --data_dir="{$DATA_DIR}"  --fine_tune=True   --initial_learning_rate=0.001   --input_queue_memory_factor=1   --batch_size=64 --max_steps=100 --pretrained_model_checkpoint_path="/home/tensorflow/inception-v3/model.ckpt-157585"`

I have tried to continue training by this command:

`bazel-bin/inception/flowers_train   --train_dir="{$TRAIN_NEW_DIR}"   --data_dir="{$DATA_DIR}"  --fine_tune=False   --initial_learning_rate=0.001   --input_queue_memory_factor=1   --batch_size=64 --max_steps=2000 --checkpoint_dir="{$TRAIN_DIR}"`

Please, can anyone explain me, what I do wrong when initializing trained model?

Comment: did you manage to fix this or find out what was going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by  using the right arg_scope like follows:

`with slim.arg_scope(inception_v3.inception_v3_arg_scope()):
    logits, _ = inception_v3.inception_v3(eval_inputs, num_classes=1001, is_training=False)`